# Mapping one key to multiple values with @Component

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, annotations

I would like to go from an old `util:map` XML annotation from a component-oriented map. I am stumbling upon this issue. I already managed to change a first one, with this type of configuration:

Mapped bean:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, MyType>    typeMap;
```

And for each Bean:

```
@Component("firstType")
public FirstType implements MyType    {}
```

Then simply calling:

```
typeMap.get("firstType");
```

works like a charm. However, here's how this other map is implemented:

```
<util:map id="routingMap">
    <entry key="one" value-ref="firstReference" />
    <entry key="two" value-ref="firstReference" />
    <entry key="three" value-ref="firstReference" />
    <entry key="four" value-ref="secondReference" />
    <entry key="five" value-ref="secondReference" />
    <entry key="six" value-ref="secondReference" />
    <entry key="seven" value-ref="thirdReference" />
    <entry key="eight" value-ref="secondReference" />
    <entry key="nine" value-ref="secondReference" />
</util:map>
```

As you can see, there are multiple keys that refer to `firstReference` and `secondReference`. Is there a way to simulate this with an annotation like:

`@Component(values = "one", "two", "three")`

and achieve a similar result ? Or is there no way to do this with Spring annotations ?

Comment: try @Component (values={"one","two","three"}

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using `@Component`, There is an open ticket for this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6736.

However you can achieve this using `@Bean`
Remove `@Component` from your implementation classes.

```
public FirstType implements MyType    {}
```

Create a config class like this

```
@Configuration
Class Config {

   @Bean(name = "one", "two", "three")
   public FirstType myFirstTypeMethod() {
      return new FirstType();
   }
}
```